# Why is this SVG Path showing incorrect width and height on Firefox?

Tags: d3.js, svg, stroke

I am new to D3 and SVG and trying to draw a custom shape using SVG path on OSX Firefox 61.0.2 and this is the code below

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1800)
  .attr("height", 600)

function drawCandle(x, y, width, upper, body, lower){
  var path = d3.path()
  // path.moveTo(x + width/2, y)
  // path.lineTo(x + width/2, y + upper + body + lower)
  path.moveTo(x, y + upper)
  path.lineTo(x + width, y + upper)
  path.closePath()
  return path
}

var p = svg.append('path')
console.log(p.style('stroke-width'))

p.attr('d', drawCandle(200,100,20, 50, 100, 80))
```

The generated Path when inspected in the developer tools looks like this

```
<svg width="1800" height="600"><path d="M200,150L220,150Z"></path></svg>
```

If I were to however hover using the Inspector on the element, it shows the width as 24 x 4
[image]

Am I missing something here? Shouldnt this be 20 x 1
My CSS currently is

```
path{
  stroke: blue;
  shape-rendering:crispEdges;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's related to the way `stroke-miterlimit` is being used to calculate the dimensions.  When changing `stroke-miterlimit` to `1` it adjusts the height from `4` to `1.45001`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit)

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1800)
  .attr("height", 600)

function drawCandle(x, y, width, upper, body, lower){
  var path = d3.path()
  // path.moveTo(x + width/2, y)
  // path.lineTo(x + width/2, y + upper + body + lower)
  path.moveTo(x, y + upper)
  path.lineTo(x + width, y + upper)
  path.closePath()
  return path
}

var p = svg.append('path')
console.log(p.style('stroke-width'))

p.attr('d', drawCandle(200,100,20, 50, 100, 80))
```

```css
path{
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width:1px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: unbelievable! that is the perfect answer, changing it changes the width big time, while still not as accurate as a native rect being rendered, there are definitely some changes in the dimension

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this? (supposing x,y is the top left corner of the candle):

```
path.moveTo(x, y);
  path.lineTo(x + width, y);
  path.lineTo(x + width, y + upper);
  path.lineTo(x, y + upper);
  path.closePath();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/ozd10hq9/

Also the difference you observe because developer tool's DOM rect is vendor dependent, Firefox adds the stroke-width, chrome does not. Under the hood, the client rect is correct in both, you can verify if you do:

```
console.log(p.node().getBBox());//SVGRect { x: 200, y: 100, width: 20, height: 30 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/k0t4pfjz/

Comment: Thanks but the question was why is the width being shown incorrectly, here is the complete candle https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/LBqwZp if you notice in the inspect element section, it seems it is more than 20 in width

Comment: Because viewBox attribute is not there, Do you want it to be 1 to 1?

Comment: yup 1: 1 in width and height

Comment: I tried adding viewBox to the same pen and the size is still 24 x 34, the width has been declared as 20 , even if it adds stroke to both sides, it would only be 22 not 24, what exactly is the issue, i have updated the pen

Comment: That is due to the stroke-width being taken into account in firefox calculation. set stroke-width to 0, you will get same 20 x 30

Comment: but if the stroke width is set to 0 the line disappears whereas the closed area remains

Comment: What is reported and what is acutal is different. Do this on console: `console.log(p.node().getBBox());` it will report a rect with 20 30 in firefox as well, but the developer tools will add the stroke-width. That's vendor implementation.

Comment: thank you very much, that explains everything! so should i do something like take the stroke width into account or just let things be as they are

Comment: No, only take into account what is reported by getBBox as it is an SVGRect, DOMRect is vendor implemented, for instance getBoundingClientRect returns DOMRect, so it will report 24x34. Take into account the getBBox.